# How to handle the overlay of kable output with page number?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, kable, rnw

I use **kbl()** function, in a rnw file that I compile in a pdf with knitr, to make a table starting from a dataframe. I use kableExtra option **scale_down** to adapt the table size to page size. It works fine but the table overlay with the page number of my pdf output. I'd like to know what's the best way to handle this type of problem. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add some Latex code that puts the tabular environment into a box and resizes the content. Below is an example using `\resizebox`

Here's `tab`, a LaTex table with Gaussian random numbers generated by `kable`:

````
```{r, message = F, warning=F}
library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

ncol <- 10
nrow <- 30
df <- map_dfc(1:ncol, ~ data.frame(round(rnorm(nrow), 2))) %>% 
  set_names(letters[1:ncol])

tab <- kbl(df, format = "latex")
```
````

And here's how to resize it by text height/width using `resizebox` (see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13809/resizing-a-table-by-textheight) on tex.stackexchange for details on how the scaling works)

````
```{r, results='asis'}
cat(
"\\begin{table}
\\centering
\\resizebox*{\\textwidth}{\\dimexpr\\textheight-2\\baselineskip\\relax}{%",
tab,
"\n}
\\end{table}"
)
```
````

**Result for the 30x10 table**

[image]

Let's double rows and columns (`ncol <- 20; nrow <- 60`)

**Result for 60x20 table.**

[image]

Comment: Do you know how I can see the full LaTeX code produced by kable function? I'm using a .rnw file and not a Rmarkdown document. Thanks

Comment: Are you using the RStudio IDE/R GUI? Then you could just return the `tab` object in the console. Otherwise, you could use `cat(tab)` in a code chunk without any additional options and knit (this will print the tex code in the PDF document).

Answer (score 1):

I have three suggestions. The first one is maybe set your table to the next page using `\newpage` in your Rmarkdown code which is latex code. The second option is maybe set `latex_options="HOLD_position"` in your `Kable_styling` function. This will set the table at a certain place which maybe could help your problem. The third option is using 'longtable = TRUE` which means that the table continues on the next page. Here is the code for option one and two with:

````
```{r}
library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20)

kable(df) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "HOLD_position")

```

\newpage

```{r}

kable(df) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "HOLD_position")

```
````

Which looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code for option three:

````
```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:50, y = 11:60)

kable(df, "latex", longtable = T, booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"), font_size = 7) 
```
````

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm already in a new page. The table is so big that if I don't use scale_down I can't have it complete in the output pdf file. The fact is that scale-down adapt table size to the page size properly but doesn't consider the presence of page number.

Comment: @Vincenzo, I just added a third option which continues the table on next page.